# what is the meaning of lookup algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, b-tree, avl-tree

I am a bit confused a term "lookup algorithm of avl trees". When I have searched this in google, I see so many website with related about b-tree not avl tree.

So, Is b-tree algorithm equal lookup algorithm of avl tree ?
If not, what is "lookup algorithm of avl tree" ? Moreover, what is the meaning of "lookup algorithm"? Please give me a link, of course if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`b-tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is a data structure - a generalized [`binary tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).

A lookup algorithm is an algorithm used to lookup values in the data structure. It is how you decide to find items in the data structure.

An [`avl tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) is a type of `b-tree` (in the abstract).

Comment: Strongly disagree, look at wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree): Not to be confused with Binary tree.

Comment: @Dewfy 'The B-tree is a generalization of a binary search tree' well, the article says just that, doesn't it?

Comment: @jv42 mammals is generalization of cat. Dog is mammal, so cat=dog? Well B-tree is INSTANCE-OF multinode tree, binary is KIND-oF multinode.

Comment: @Dewfy - Your logic seems rather flawed. Saying that a cat is a mammal and that a dog is a mammal doesn't mean that I say the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Dewfy well, you can go edit Wikipedia if you don't feel it's adequate.

Answer (score 1):

The lookup algorithm is just the way that you look through the nodes in the tree to find a specific value.

An [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) is a [self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), so the lookup algorithm of an AVL tree is the exact same as for a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).

A [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is not the same thing as a binary tree, so it has a different lookup algorithm. The difference is that in a B-tree each node can have several values and more than two children, so the lookup algorithm follows the same basic principle as for a binary tree, but it's a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

AVL tree is kind of balancing in the binary tree. B-tree is abbreviation for "Bayer-tree" - a kind of multinode (exceeding 2) tree. So these algorithms are different, since look-up in B-tree takes also look-up  over particular page

Comment: you mean lookup = search ?  and Can you explain a bit more "lookup over particular page" ?

Comment: @fatai it is little bit about terminology. The most common case of B-tree usage is database-engines, where simultaneously only part of nodes loaded in memory, but another are on disk. So in this case node=page. Page contains multiple entries of data (look at picture on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). So to look-up element you need (a) go over tree (b) go over particular page. For example,  in the (b), binary search can be applied.